# How to make command "Hadoop" work in linux 18.04?

Tags: linux, path

I installed Hadoop and now it works with command `/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop`.
Where and how should I add this path to make command `hadoop` work without a full path to file? I already tried .bashrc and /etc/environment, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add it to your PATH environment variable. PATH is used to find programs to run in the shell.

To see what your current PATH is you can type

```
$ echo $PATH
```

When you update the PATH variable you want to make sure you don't delete previous entries.

```
$ PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/hadoop/bin
```